# Can I create an ambient transaction for testing?

Tags: sql-server, testing, transactions, transactionscope

My current system has a rather aggressive data layer that creates an SqlDatabase instance for me by calling a static method. I pass in a stored procedure name (string) and the magic just happens.

I want to try and get some of this crazy system under test and so want to control what is in the database.

Having realised that this structure

```
[Test]
public void Should_do_some_thing()
{   
  using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                CleanUpDatabase();
                SetupDatabaseData();

                //Run Test

                Assert.That(someResult,Is.EqualTo("ExpectedValue");

                scope.Dispose();
            }
}
```

does what I want (no database changes persist outside the test) It would clearly be nicer if I could set up the transaction within a `[SetUp]` method and remove without committing in the `[TearDown]` section.

Is this possible?

Note I cannot call any methods on a `command` object or whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` to do the set up/clean up:

```
private TransactionScope scope;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    scope = new TransactionScope();
    CleanUpDatabase();
    SetupDatabaseData();
}

[Test]
public void Should_do_some_thing()
{   
    //Run Test

    Assert.That(someResult,Is.EqualTo("ExpectedValue");
}

[TestCleanup]
public void CleanUp()
{
    scope.Dispose();
}
```

You may need to add error handling etc but this is the basics of it:

[TestInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx):

> Identifies the method to run before the test to allocate and configure resources needed by all tests in the test class. This class cannot be inherited.

[TestCleanUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx):

> Identifies a method that contains code that must be used after the test has run and to free resources obtained by all the tests in the test class. This class cannot be inherited.

If you are using NUNIT then you can use `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` instead of `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanUp]` respectively.

Comment: Hmm I did not think that would 'just work' but it sure does! Thanks.

Comment: You basically had it figured out in your question anyway (the idea of setup/teardown) I just helped put it together!